# How to connect MySQL Workbench to an existing ODBC Data Source

Tags: windows, odbc, mysql-workbench

I have an existing ODBC data source that goes to an Oracle database. I want to use MySQL Workbench to query that database.  How can I connect MySQL Workbench to that excising ODBC Data Source?

I'm running on Windows 11.
In the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) my connection uses the Oracle in InstantClient_19_16 driver.

[View ODBC Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJp8j.png)

In MySQL Workbench I go to Database > Connect to Database. The pop-up window has a place to select from saved connection settings but there are none there. There is a place to select a Connection Method but none of the choices are for ODBC.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL Workbench only uses ODBC to connect to databases other than MySQL as part of its "migration wizard" feature. In other words, MySQL Workbench is not intended to be a general-purpose database administration tool like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/); it is focused on MySQL just like SSMS is focused on SQL Server.